# Github - Have gifs play at the same time

Tags: github

I included 40+ gifs in my github readme but the issue I am facing is that they do not start and stop at the time. I created the gifs myself so I can verify that they are of the same length and have the same delay between each image.

Does anyone have any suggestion how I can make these gifs play together ? Below is an example of the code that I use.

```
![Alt Text](https://github.com/fakeuser/temp/blob/master/results/0-3-shape.gif)
```

Comment: Have you checked it in different browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to preload them, through a [javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6879554/6309), but not GitHub repo markdown would allow you that level of control.

It would then be easier to display static gifs, with a link to an external page where you can run javascripts and better control the pre-loading of the animated gifs.